# Validity of argument

Tags: propositional-calculus

I am trying to validate the following argument using a truth table, but I get stuck:

> If you invest in this business, then you get the profit. You didn't invest in this business. Therefore, you didn't get the profit.

Comment: Not valid: $P \to Q, \lnot P \nvDash \lnot Q$. See [Denying the antecedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent).

Comment: The argument is valid when, in all cases when the premises are TRUE, also the conclusion is. Consider the row of the tuth table enetred for $P$ FALSE and $Q$ TRUE.

Comment: What does your truth table look like?

Comment: I've aready seen this.

Answer (score 1):

You say $A \implies B$, so $\neg A \implies \neg B$. We conclude the first statement  is false if only if we observe '$A \wedge \neg B$', while we conclude the second one is false if and only if we observe '$\neg A \wedge B$', therefore the two are not equivalent and do not yield the same truth table. Consider a statement like 'all cows are animals, so if we observe something that is not a cow, then it is not an animal', which would be true according to your logic. But the observed object might still be a chicken, for example. You're statement if true if we would have $A \iff B$, so using your example, 'you get rich if and only if you invest in business'.

Answer (score 0):

> If you eat cyanide, you will die.
>
> You did not eat cyanide, therefore you will not die.

Does this sound correct to you? It is logically equivalent to your statement (*hint*: what if you ate botox?).